# Increment and return a field of a Django 1.3 object async and ensure uniqueness

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a method in my model that increments a field of my Django object and returns the value, but I can't call this method async without getting duplicate values. I've read in the Django documentation about transaction.atomic but I'm using Django 1.3 why I can't use it.

This is what the method looks like:

```
def incr_and_return_val(self):
    obj = Obj.objects.filter(pk=self.id) 
    obj.update(val=F('val') + 1)
    return obj.val
```

What do I do to ensure that this method always returns a unique value.

Thanks, Mattias

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/transactions/

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your function with `transaction.commit_on_success`

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_on_success
def incr_and_return_val(self):
```

Transactions in Django 1.3 (and newer  versions too) are tied to request scope, so when a request is created then transaction begins, when request ends (response is returned) then transaction is commited and closed. If any exception is raised during request, then transaction is rolledback.

With this decorator you create new transaction for this function that will be commited after successful call.